# How does the combining of programming languages work?

Tags: programming-languages

Firstly I'm really sorry to ask this, but I ran out of searchword ideas.
I'm really curious about how big projects can use different programming languages in the same program. For example League of Legends uses the following languages:

```
C++ (the core game is written in this) 
Lua (core game) C# (game tools)
ActionScript (game hud and pvp.net) 
Java (platform servers) 
Erlang (platform servers) 
Php/sql (web team / platform)
```

How can I achieve to make different programming languages work together? (like C++ and C#) Why is it good to do it? Does it make things easier? I'm open to everything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each language lends itself to a certain class of tasks. For example, PHP has many features geared toward web-server tasks, while ActionScript would not be useful in such an environment. You can see this in your breakdown, how each language is closely related to the tasks assigned to it.

So it is good to use multiple languages if your goals call for the use of multiple languages. As for making the different languages work together, that is a very large and technical question. You will find that each language has its own ways of interfacing with other languages, and there are often many technical details that must be learned.